# Submitting nested object to REST controller

Tags: java, rest, model-view-controller, jackson

I have an HTML form which has an 'nested' object within. 
If I send an enitty only with pure attributes, without another entities inside, it is ok, but to send form to a REST controller using ajax, an exception is thrown not event reaching controller because this 'nested' object is not reconignzed as an attribute of main entity sent, which is `Product`.

I can got data in two differentes `jquery` ways in ajax operation:

```
$.param($('form').serializeArray())
"id=&type.id=1&name=One"
```

and

```
JSON.stringify($('form').serializeArray())
"[{"name":"id","value":""},{"name":"type.id","value":"1"},{"name":"name","value":"One"}]"
```

And in this last case, of course I can create a `$.each` `jquery` function to convert entirely object.
But is there any way to easily convert it using `jquery` ou a well configured jackson mapper object?

Here are form, ajax calling, java entities and controller.

Form:

```
<form>
   <input type="hidden" name="id"/>
   <select id="type.id">
     <option value='1'>One</option>
     <!-- ... -->
   </select>
   <input type="text" id="name"/>
</form>
```

Entities:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    @ManyToOne
    private Type type;
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 250)
    private String name;

    /* getters and setters */
}

@Table
@Entity
public class Type {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(length = 5)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    /* getters and setters */
}
```

ajax submitted in some button:

```
$.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "create",
        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType : "json",
        data : /* 
                here stands the doubt. How serialize my form?
                */,
        success : function(data) {
            if (data === true) {
                alert('Success!');
            } else {
                console.log('Some error');
            }
        }
    });
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Boolean create(@RequestBody Domain model) throws Exception {
    try {
        getService().create(model);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I just misunderstood your question.
This is another solution that give the form selector and return json object.

```
function serializeForm(formSelector){
  var params = $.param($(formSelector).serializeArray());
  var jsonStr = '{"'+params.replace(/"/g, '\\"').replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g,'":"')+'"}';
  var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
  return jsonObj;
}

var formJsonData = serializeForm('form');
```

Comment: But if main object has another object as a field of main object, as in my question example 'type.id'. The object mapper can't find 'type.id' as a Product field and throws an exception. That's main problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is another object serializer.

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

Comment: I just tried that, @Ghokun, but as I said in comment in another answer: If main object has another object as a field of main object, as in my question example 'type.id'. The object mapper can't find 'type.id' as a Product field and throws an exception. That's main problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST , headers = "Accept=application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, String> create(@RequestBody Domain model) throws Exception {
    HashMap<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();
    try {
        getService().create(model);
        result.put("status",true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        result.put("status",false);
    }
    return result;
}
```

ajax submitted in some button:

```
$.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "create",
        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType : "json",
        data : /* 
                here stands the doubt. How serialize my form?
                */,
        success : function(data) {
            if (data.status === true) {
                alert('Success!');
            } else {
                console.log('Some error');
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank for try help me, Steven. But the main question remais: How serialize form?